# What will happen for an Openstack instance if a server (Node) go offline?

Tags: instance, openstack, offline, high-availability, redundancy

I'm new to OpenStack and have a basic question about it. Assume that we have 3 Master node (Controller) and 10 Slave node (Compute node) in our cloud. We make 50 VMs (Instances) on the cloud. What will happen if one node (Controller or Compute node) become offline (Failure)? What is the best solution to prevent shutting down a VM if a server get offline?

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question requires more than a short Stackoverflow answer. Here are a few initial thoughts.

When a controller goes offline, the instance itself continues running, but if the failed controller hosts a router, the instance might be cut off from the network. Generally, if the controller has anything that the instance needs, that thing won't be available anymore. There are measures like HA routers that can help in such a case.

When the instance's compute host goes down, the instance doesn't run anymore. You can `evacuate` instances from a failed compute host, which means that they are rebuilt on different hosts. If an instance's root disk resides on a volume or an ephemeral disk that is shared with other compute hosts, this means a mere instance reboot. If the instance has an ephemeral disk inside the failed host, it must be rebuilt from scratch.

OpenStack has a project named Masakari whose goal is to make instances resilient by redundancy. In short, instance HA. The application keeps running even if an instance crashes.

By the way, *master* and *slave* are not correct terminology in this context. Use *controller* and *compute* instead.

Comment: Thank you.
So what is your final suggest? What is best scenario for high availability in the cloud? We don't have any hardware limitation.

Comment: if there were a best scenario, there would be a single solution. There are many solutions, and some are well adapted to your needs, which I don't know. My recommendation is you research options that make sense for your requirements.